# Integrating a toolbar for application

Tags: android, xml, layout, menu

I'm trying to integrate a bottom tool bar into my application.
The bar will be used in a number of different activities so I am using the following line in my XML to include it with each layout:

```
<include
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    layout="@layout/test2" />
```

The output for test2.xml is as follows:

[image]

When I include it in my main activity the output looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have it so that the bar appears as close to the bottom as possible..I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

My activity_main.xml file looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/homeTitle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/orderbtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/viewbtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/feedbackBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/feedbackbtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/payBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/paybtn" />

    <include
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    layout="@layout/test2" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you are doing this instead of using the action bar?

Comment: I also added this remark in my answer ;-) Please Javacadabra, do NOT use this bottom bar!

Comment: Yeah, Looked into using the action bar, read about how it's recommended not to use a bottom bar. However for my application I think the UI would look very unusual if these buttons were at the top as opposed to the bottom.

Comment: I only saw your comment @Waza_Be after replying to the previous comment. I personally think It would be a lot easier to use the action bar the only thing is I feel the design would look very strange...

Comment: I don't like to be rude, but you are doing a HUGE mistake. First, a Home button has no reason at all to exist. Second, your buttons would be close to the soft navigation buttons. Third, you will hurt your user.

Comment: have you seen a single application in the Android OS that use this navigation pattern? We have not the same perception of "unusual" and "strange"

Comment: Your not being rude, I appreciate the feedback, This is a project for college so I am learning! The idea behind the home button was not to return the user to the home screen of the device but rather to bring the user from whatever screen they were on to the main activity which acts as a dashboard. I do see what you mean in relation to the soft nav buttons though!

Comment: In reply to your previous comment does the twitter application not have a bottom menu bar?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21730/discussion-between-javacadabra-and-waza-be)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in a Relative Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

     <include
         android:layout_height="0dip"
         layout="@layout/test2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout at the top of the BottomBar should have these attributes:

```
<Linearlayout
    ....
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     />
```

While your bottom bar should have

```
<Linearlayout
    ....
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

**BE CAREFULL:**

This is not related to your question, but such bottom bars belong to the iPhone.

The Home button should in fact looks like a up button: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

And the three other parts should belong to the ActionBar: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html